# Why is the (PyQt5) QWidget not being added to the QBoxLayout

Tags: user-interface, pyqt, python-3.4, pyqt5

Right so essentially I am creating a user interface and have attempted to add a QtWidgets.QLineEdit to a QVBoxLayout as well as a QtWidgets.QLabel to a different QVBoxLayout. Unfortunately it is not working and throwing up an error:

```
   in build_gui_adddata_device
       self.labellayout.addWidget(self.labelsupplierid)
   TypeError: QBoxLayout.addwidget(QWidget; int stretch=0, Qt.Alignment alignment=0): first argument of unbound = method must have type QBoxLayout
```

I have defined labellayout as thus:

```
    print("e")
    self.labellayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout
```

"e" was printed, which is how I know that there is no issue with the definition of the layout itself.

Just for reference this is the QtWidget I was trying to add:

```
     print("f")
    self.labelsupplierid = QtWidgets.QLabel("Supplier ID: ")
```

Again "f" was printed
This is the line that is causing the problem:

```
    print("i")
    self.labellayout.addWidget(self.labelsupplierid)
```

I don't understand why my code isn't working, I am honestly perplexed. My syntax seems to be correct and I have made other build_gui functions that have executed exactly the same type of code (with different widgets, might I add) that have been successful.

Please can someone enlighten me. Many Thanks.

Comment: `self.labellayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()` <---

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I missed that aha